# How to drag and reorder the content in angular 6

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6

I am using ngx-input-file for uploading the images. Please look at the below example.

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-input-file?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

If i drag and drop the image here, it will upoad that image. How can I reorder those images, like first image as last or middle anywhere.It should change the order. Please help me how can I do this?

Its really critical for me. I'm new to angular 6. Please help me to do this in angular 2 or 4 or 5 or 6.

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind to the `ngModel` attribute of `input-file`, which will return an array:

```
<input-file inputId="input-file" [(ngModel)]="files" placeholder="Drop files below!"></input-file>
```

The order of the elements within `files` determines how they're shown on screen. For example, to reverse the sort order, you could do `this.files.reverse()`. Just move the array elements into your desired sort order.

**[Here is a StackBlitz demo showing reverse](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-input-file-72wxgp?file=src/app/app.component.html)**

Comment: Thank you so much. But I want to drag and reorder. Not button click.

Comment: In that case, I don't think you'll be able to use `ngx-input-file`. From this question and the other one you've just posted, it sounds like you'll need to create your own component

Comment: I am new to angular, I don't know how to create. Can you please help me to do this?

Comment: `ngx-input-file` is open source and hosted on [Github](https://github.com/rsaenen/ngx-input-file#readme), that might be a good place to start

Comment: i want to drag and drop the image function and need to drag and reorder those image. I didn't find any example. So i posted here.